# Why is my simple makefile only printing the rule?

Tags: c, makefile

My makefile is written as follows:

```
all: hello

hello: hello.c
    gcc hello.c -o hello
```

When I type 'make' into the terminal, the rule `gcc hello.c -o hello` is printed, but not run. I can tell because no .o files are being created. If I type in the rule to the terminal, it works as expected. I'm using vim to edit the file. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The command `gcc hello.c -o hello` will not generate any `.o` files. It will only generate the output file you've requested, `hello`.

You would normally write your `Makefile` more like this:

```
all: hello

hello: hello.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $<
```

That is, the executable depends on the object files (`.o`), and `make`'s built-in rules know how to generate `.o` files from `.c` files.

Answer (score 1):

To generate object files, use `-c` flag.

```
gcc -c hello.c
```

For example,

```
all: hello

hello: hello.o
    gcc -o hello hello.o

hello.o: hello.c
    gcc -c hello.c
```